# Do questions about how to build a program by specifying what it needs to do belong here?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I think the best way to ask this question is with an example:

> "Hello stack overflow! I want to build an app with:
>
> 1. Feature
> 2. Feature
> 3. Feature
>
> I have no idea how to even try to build it and there are no tutorials on google and the documentation isn't very helpful. Can you point me at the right direction?"

Is Stack Overflow the right place for such a question, considering it's very specific? If not, will breaking it into multiple question asking how to build each feature will make it (a) good question(s)?

Comment: There are several ways to say "of course not!"  It is not clear which way you prefer.

Comment: 'considering it's very specific?' it won't be.  There has never yet been a requirement or functional specification that is both comprehensive enough to allow a viable design and also short enough for an SO question.  SO OP's are notorious for failing to supply information that is required for answers, often to the point of seeming to be deliberately withholding data:(   There is no chance at all of question such as you suggest being useful to future SO users/visitors.  They are just requests for work to be done for no money, similar to slavery but without the food and accommodation.

Answer (score 17):

Such a question is going to be *way* too broad.

SO is not a place to get an entire tutorial on a topic as an answer.

Breaking it into a few questions is almost certainly not going to sufficiently narrow down such a question, given how you've described it.

Comment: What about asking about each desired feature at a time? Will that be good? Also do you have any idea why I am being downvoted?

Comment: 'What about asking about each desired feature at a time? Will that be good?' no, it will be a timewaster.  You will get answers that prevent the other features you want being implemented efficiently, or at all.  The supposed-to-be Q&A will then degenerate into the typical 'help-vampire' death-spiral of comments.

Comment: @MartinJames i see. If so, how should I go about implementing features that have no tutorials for them? I am beginning to advance beyond the "beginner" phase and have no idea how to bridge the gap between vision and execution.

Comment: @BarAkiva the same way all of us did. Research and practice. Even if you are paying for education (which is not mandatory), those two bits you'll have to do yourself.

Comment: @BarAkiva Don't get so hung up on finding exact tutorials that match what you're trying to do. Overwhelmingly, programming is about problem solving. Play with code and find your own solutions. Knowing how to do that effectively though takes practice. Honestly, my "unproductive" days of banging my head against a wall in thought were some of the most productive days I've ever had.

Comment: Research, prototype. Keep it small and simple and iterate often. You'll end up throwing tons of work away, but the knowledge you will have gained will be invaluable down the road.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thats good advice. But sometimes you don't even know where to start in order to execute on an idea. What to do then?

Comment: @BarAkiva Practice. If you sit on a problem and are unable to write literally any code, that's likely a sign that you're trying to progress too fast, and may want to switch to something easier to help build up your knowledge toolbelt. Learning to break projects down into tiny manageable parts and play until you make progress is a skill that takes a *long* time, and is grueling in the beginning. It can be significantly helped by using a REPL though.

Comment: @BarAkiva  It looks like you write JS. Throw code at the browser console until things start making sense. Try stuff. Experiment. When you're first learning, unless you've needed to have an "engineer mindset" before, you'll be learning three things at the same time: programming in general, the language you're using, and problem solving in general. Each thing will need to be practiced, but you can practice them all at once just by playing. The console/REPL is great because the instant feedback it gives is great for learning. You can try the same code is 1000 different ways and see what happens.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you. I have transitioned from JS to Java and android development, but I get your point. Break into smaller problems.

Answer (score 7):

To address the comment on the other answer: even if you broke the question down and asked about one specific aspect, that would still be too broad, and asking about tutorial recommendations.

- Broad questions like that are offtopic because they're unlikely to help anyone in the future. The exact reason you're confused is unlikely to also be the exact reason someone else will be confused. If you were running into a specific problem that someone can search for later though (like a specific error message), that would be a different story.

  A good example of this would be Code Review, which is meant for subjective, broad questions. How many times have you searched for a problem and been directed to Code Review for the answer? For me, never. The questions are far too personalized to be readily helpful to other people. Someone browsing may read something helpful in a review, but it's highly unlikely that they were directed there via a search regarding something specific.
- Library recommendations are offtopic because they're highly subjective, and turn into a readily outdated list of suggestions that requires regular maintenance. There's no definite answer, so it's not a good fit for the site.

---

You need to get a start yourself, and ask a specific question regarding your attempt. If you have no idea where to start, you need to keep reading/trying until you get to the point where you can get a start.